# Paperclip doesn't work showing multiple has_attached_model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model called advertiser and it 5 url for image upload

Here the model

```
  attr_accessible :link, :publishoff, :publishon, :title, :adone, :adtwo, :adthree, :adfour, :adfive
  has_attached_file :adone, :styles => {
        :small => "150x150>",
        :medium => "300x300>",
        :thumb => "100x100>"
    },
    :url  => "/assets/advertiser/adone/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
    :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/advertiser/adone/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

Where adone adtwo are my image upload and so on, all have the same idea of upload.

Now the view looks like this

```
8: <% unless @advertisments.nil? %>
9: <%= link_to image_tag(@advertisments.adone.url(:small), :title =>"#{@advertisments.title}"), @advertisments.link, :target => "_blank" %>
10: <% end %>
```

And here my controller
application_controller

```
@advertisments = Advertiser.where("publishon <= ? AND publishoff >= ?", Date.today, Date.today).limit(1)
```

The error i get is the following

```
undefined method `adone' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller method is returning an `ActiveRecord::Relation` collection... the object you want is inside of it.

Add `.first` to the end of this line, like so:

```
@advertisments = Advertiser.where("publishon <= ? AND publishoff >= ?", Date.today, Date.today).limit(1).first
```

This will return the only `Advertiser` from within the collection and assign it to `@advertisements`.